# When importing scrapy on windows 7x64, ImportError: No module named twisted

Tags: scrapy, twisted, windows-7-x64

I have followed all of the steps on http://steamforge.net/wiki/index.php/How_to_Install_Scrapy_in_64-bit_Windows_7 , but cannot seem to import scrapy to start working with it. I have installed basically every dependent program at least twice at this point, including pywin32. Every time I start up python and attempt to import scrapy, I get a "No module named twisted" error message.

EDIT:Robin, I am pretty sure twisted is installed correctly, but I don't know how to select which environment it uses; only the python 2.7 environment pops up as an option when I try to install twisted, but I also have anaconda installed. 
I have tried importing twisted from both command line interfaces. In anaconda, it is able to find the scrapy when I import it, but cannot then find twisted.
When I attempt to open scrapy in python2.7, it just says no module named scrapy. However, when I try to import twisted it works just fine.
I think everything would be ok if I could get one or the other into the opposite folder, but I don't know how to do that.

Jean-Paul, the full path for python2.7 is C:\python27\python.exe ; the full path for anaconda is: C:\anaconda\python.exe
the import Scrapy traceback is:

```
C:\Anaconda>python
Python 2.7.5 |Anaconda 1.8.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  1 2013, 12:37:52) [MSC v.1
500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import scrapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.22.0-py2.7.egg\scrapy\__init__.py
    ", line 43, in <module>
    from twisted import version as _txv
ImportError: No module named twisted
>>> import easy_install
>>> easy_install scrapy
  File "<stdin>", line 1
easy_install scrapy
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

and the traceback in python2.7 is:

```
Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 07:43:08) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scrapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named scrapy
>>>
```

I hope that is enough, I would give you all of the files that were installed when twisted was, but I have no idea how to give you a list like that. Thanks for the help, and sorry for being a n00b.

Comment: Hate to be that guy, but are you sure twisted is correctly installed? And in the environment python uses?

Comment: Add more information.  How are you launching Python?  What is the full path to the Python executable you are running?  What files were added to your filesystem when you installed Twisted?  What is the full path to the directory they were installed to?  What is the complete traceback you get when you try to `import scrapy`?  "It doesn't work" is almost never a question that can be answered except in the most trivial, boring cases.

Comment: I would suggest using the Python(x,y) distribution witch comes with an IDE and many popular packages, then install Scrapy/Twisted by using pip from the Python(x,y) distribution. http://www.pythonxy.org